# Oracle SQL how to sort data inside a row

Tags: oracle11g

I have the following situation and looking for help to get the solution.

The field `BLOB_ITEM varchar2(4000)` has the following data and i need to sort this:

```
9-5|7-2|8-0|6-6|7-0-5|3-4|2-1|1-9
```

The result should have the smallest value replaced with `9-5` and so on.

Thanks
Shameer

Comment: The smallest value replaced with 9-5 and so on? What do you mean?

Comment: did you try to split the string into array and sort?

Comment: The answer should be the smallest value should be in first place.

Comment: How do you define smallest?

Comment: I wanted to do in a single query and i tried regexp_replace but no luck.

Comment: Your data implies that you have a many-to-one relationship that you have implemented using the worst possible technique (aka anti-pattern "maximum badness").  Instead, break each value into a single row in a table instead of storing them all in one row.

Comment: '7|2|3|9|5' then answer should be '2|3|5|7'

Comment: But your posted input before is different to this! And the `9` should go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just query the row then process it in java.

The easiest would be:

```
String[] data = row.split("\\|");
Arrays.sort(data);
```

Depending on exactly how you want it sorted you will probably need to define a custom comparator for the sort.

Comment: Since `String.split` uses a regular expression as parameter, you have to escape the pipe like this: `row.split("\\|");`.

Comment: i am looking for a simple query by using any function which can give the query result

Comment: it doesn't exist. It may be possible using a complex query and a lot of string functions (maybe even cursors) but it's not trivial.

Comment: So, see my complex, not untrivial solution in SQL ;)

Comment: Yeah impressively horrible :) I'd hate to need to debug any problems with that.

Comment: (Hmm, read my comment and it sounded a bit harsh - you solution is impressive but as you yourself say it's quite horrible to use, debug, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing a solution in Oracle SQL, try the following:

```
WITH t AS
 (SELECT BLOB_ITEM str FROM your_table) -- '9-5|7-2|8-0|6-6|7-0-5|3-4|2-1|1-9'
SELECT listagg(vals, '|') within GROUP(ORDER BY 1)
FROM   (SELECT TRIM(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) vals
        FROM   t t,
               TABLE(xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || REPLACE(t.str, '|', '</e><e>') || '</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x);
```

This firstly splits your data by `|` with some XML functions. After that it joins the elements back while ordering it.

This is in fact a horrible usage, but if you have a horrible data model, you will get a horrible solution ;)

Comment: Thanks, But when I fired against my table it gives the following 'ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too longerror.'

Comment: So, how many different elements do you have in your single column? The point is, that it will create some XML in the inner like `<e>9-5</e><e>7-2</e>`. So it will add 7 chars for each element like `9-5` to the line. If this will reach a limit of 4000 characters, if will end up in this ORA exception, though...

Comment: As you mentioned it is giving horrible result. Concatenation is too long.

Comment: You are right! So, why not facing the real problem, the data model? ;)

Comment: Do you have any solution in your memory for this? I can't change the data Model :)

Comment: Don't know, if there is an even horribler SQL solution. I didn't figure it out yet. ;) The fact, that you've tagged this question with `Java`, i would recommend to do this with Java. Like Tim B said, it will be much more easier to find errors.